# Android Gradle build problems

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to import project from old Android studio into new version. Project includes Cordova lib. And I have big problems with gradle.
Currently,I have this problem `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

This is code from gradle.build

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

ext.multiarch=false

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
        compile project(subproject)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode Integer.parseInt("" + getVersionCodeFromManifest() + "0")
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    if (multiarch || System.env.BUILD_MULTIPLE_APKS) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}

def getVersionCodeFromManifest() {
    def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
}

def getProjectList() {
    def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    def projects = []
    while (matcher.find()) {
      projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
    }
    return projects
}
```

Some section of the code is highlighted with exception `dependencies cannot be applied to (groovy.lang.Closure)`.
And this is gradle.properties

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern


    def getProjectList() {
    def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    def projects = []
    while (matcher.find()) {
      projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
    }
    return projects
}

for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
    include subproject
}

include ':'
```

I don't know exactly what this exception is, and have no idea how to solve this problems.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted many hours trying to solve the same problem and found it was much easier to simply make an entirely new project in your new version of Android studio, create activities/fragments with exactly the same names, and then copy/paste all of the java, xml, images, etc.

Comment: Yes, I have done this every time I had similar problems, but now I have project which use CordovaLib(I have no experience with it) and it has lots of folders and files. I found that its easier to remove this problems than trying to migrate Cordova's files to new project.